# Python Twisted and Corepost

Tags: python, http, rest, web, twisted

I'm writing a REST API with Python, Twisted and the Corepost library (https://github.com/jacek99/corepost), which is pretty nice. However, I have run into one issue I'm not sure how to solve. Corepost provides functionality to define filter classes that get called on the request and on the response to provide a "hook" to pre and post process things.

I've defined a post (response) filter, but it's not being called. Looking at the source code the response generation is bailing out early before my filter is being called because the response is a Deferred, and it's letting Twisted handle it natively.

My code is structured like this (abbreviated):

```
 @route("/<resource_id>", Http.GET)
 @defer.inlineCallbacks
 def get_json(self, request, resource_id, **kwargs):
     # my get handling code here
```

Is there a way to get my filter called in this instance?